# Hide server element div in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have div in aspx page with the `runat="server"` attribute. How can I hide this element in javascript?

```
<div id="content" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery. 
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= content.ClientID %>').hide();
    });
</script>
```